# Age calculation for observation data in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have very simple big observation data hypothetically structured as below:

```
> df = data.frame(ID = c("oak", "birch", rep("oak",2), "pine", "birch", "oak", rep("pine",2), "birch", "oak"),
+                 yearobs = c(rep(1998,3), rep(1999,2), rep(2000,3),rep(2001,2), 2002))
> df
      ID yearobs
1    oak    1998
2  birch    1998
3    oak    1998
4    oak    1999
5   pine    1999
6  birch    2000
7    oak    2000
8   pine    2000
9   pine    2001
10 birch    2001
11   oak    2002
```

What I want to do is to calculate the age by taking the difference between the years ( `max(yearobs)-min(yearobs)` ) for each unique ID (tree species in this example). I have tried to work with `lubridate` + `dplyr` packages, however, number of observations for each unique ID varies in my data and I want to create an age column in a fastest way without storing minimum and maximum values separately (avoiding for loops here since my data is huge).

Desired output:

```
     ID age
1   oak   4
2 birch   3
3  pine   3
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: ```library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(age = max(yearobs)-min(yearobs))```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In base R you can do:

```
aggregate(yearobs ~ ID, data = df, FUN = function(x) max(x) - min(x))
#      ID yearobs
# 1 birch       3
# 2   oak       4
# 3  pine       2
```

Comment: Beat me to it. My function would have been `function(x) diff(range(x))`.

Comment: So obvious, yet I was struggling with loops! "max-min" seems faster in my OS! Cool though.

Answer (score 4):

An option is to group by 'ID' and get the difference between the `min` and `max` of 'yearobs' column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise(age = max(yearobs) - min(yearobs))
```

---

Also, if we need to do this fast, then `data.table` would be another option

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(age = max(yearobs) - min(yearobs)), by = ID]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
by(df['yearobs'], df$ID, FUN = function(x) max(x)- min(x))
```

Comment: Thanks! Super fast, even though I prefer R-base options.

Comment: I upvoted actually! My bad I didn't state that in my post. Thanks again.

Comment: @DSA My point is that I was focusing on the efficiency part instead of the `base R`